# Trying to subscribe to a http call in test file, and i need to assert the observerable in my test

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular6

I need to make a HTTP call in my test and I need to verify my observeable.

When I debug the code, the HTTP call is getting called in service, but in my test, it fails and it says http is `undefined`, but while debugging I'm able to see the http observal in console.

```
          //service.ts file 
         //imports modles goes here 



  export class DataService {
      private api = this.configService.config.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private configService: AppConfigService,
        private errorService: ErrorService) 
          { 
          }
          public getCustomerList(): Observable<IUserResponse> {
                     return this.http.get<IUserResponse>`${this.api}/v1/getusers/users`);
      }

    }


 my test file serviec.specs.ts

  describe('OnboardingService', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {

     const httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() }));

    appConfigService= new AppConfigService(httpClient);

    appConfigService.config = { apiUrl:"https://test-test-getuser.json"}

    erroService = new ErrorService();

   service = new Dataservice(httpClient, appConfigService,erroService);
   it('should return an Observable<Iuser[]>', done => {

               service.getCustomerList().subscribe(response => {
          expect(response.users).toBeGreaterThan(0);
          done();
        });


    });
})
```

Comment: I guess there is a problem with this.http.get('{this.apiurl}/v1/getuser'), it should be this.http.get('${this.apiurl}/v1/getuser')

Comment: Do you have a outer logging statement? Like `console.log(this.http.get('{this.apiurl}/v1/getuser').subscribe((response)=>{console.log(response.user)}))`? You need to show more code. Please post the function where this call is made.

Comment: Can you execute this line this.http.get('{this.apiurl}/v1/getuser').subscribe(console.log) and send what the console prints ?

Comment: Need to know more about the issue to help resolve it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
this.http.get(`${this.apiurl}/v1/getuser`).subscribe((response)=>{console.log(response.user)})
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Grey right arrow shows your code to execute. Left grey arrow below shows the result of execution. Console log has no arrow in dev tools.

[image]

The result of execution `.subscribe()` is a Subscriber as you can notice in your screenshot. Your code just doesn't execute function you passed to `.subscribe()`.

So your problem is with your endpoint probably. Check the network tab in your dev tools.